# Recovery Nifi Registry from Git

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to restore a git file on Nifi and I'm getting the error

2020-05-12 16: 18: 59,872 INFO [NiFi Registry Web Server-19] oanrwmIllegalStateExceptionMapper java.lang.IllegalStateException: access tokens are issued only over HTTPS. Returning conflict response. 2020-05-12 16: 21: 36,024 INFO [NiFi Registry Web Server-43] oanrwmIllegalStateExceptionMapper java.lang.IllegalStateException: a bucket with the same name already exists. Returning conflict response.

I will be forever grateful if anyone can help me

Comment: How are you trying to restore? The log is saying that a request came in to create a bucket, but a bucket already exists with the same name

Comment: Hi @BryanBende thanks for your attention. I really need your help. I need to retrieve a stream that is saved in Git. On a new machine. My steps were as follows 1- I gave a git clone in the new registry folder. 2 - I configured Flow Persistence as it is the first time.
And open it in the browser and tried to import more the Flow does not appear.

Comment: What version of NiFi Registry?

Comment: nifi-registry-0.6.0

Comment: Ok so if you have a brand new registry, meaning no existing DB, and you point the flow storage at git and then start up, it will rebuild the DB from the git repo, is that not what is happening?

Comment: @Bryan Bende is not

Comment: the only way you could get the error you showed is if you had an existing database

Comment: @BryanBende 
If I delete the bank before I start. It works?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to start a new registry from git, then you have to start with an empty DB like I said earlier

Comment: @bryanBende  I found it doesn't work on windows

Comment: Windows is not a supported OS for registry - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/html/administration-guide.html#system-requirements